# --allow-empty-diff stopped working after upgrading to doctrine migrations 3

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4, doctrine-migrations

I have a deployment script that executes the migrations this way:

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff --allow-empty-diff --env=prod
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction --allow-no-migration --env=prod
```

And I am getting this error:

```
[ERROR] No changes detected in your mapping information.
```

Previously, before upgrading to migrations 3, the error was not being thrown. Once I upgraded it the error started to appear.

```
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "2.1.*",
"doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "3.1.*", // previously "2.2.*"
"doctrine/migrations": "3.2.*", // previously "2.2.*"
```

At first I thought that the `--allow-empty-diff` was removed in the new version, but when I run:

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff --help
```

I do see

```
--allow-empty-diff     Do not throw an exception when no changes are detected.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It displays an error, but it returns a 0 code, no ? https://github.com/doctrine/migrations/blob/4eeb7968ade885b45ab213d69ae852ff0ea9be08/lib/Doctrine/Migrations/Tools/Console/Command/DiffCommand.php#L162-L165

Comment: You are correct, checkout the older version (2.2.x) and it was just doing `writeln`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the functionality stills works the same as before. If no changes are detected, a message is printed to the console.

However, the difference between 2.2.* and 3.6.* is that it the latter uses `StyleInterface` to style the message as an error instead of using the regular `OutputInterface`.

In both cases, a exception is not thrown.

[See the code for 2.2.*](https://github.com/doctrine/migrations/blob/2.2.x/lib/Doctrine/Migrations/Tools/Console/Command/DiffCommand.php#L129)
[See the code for 3.6.*](https://github.com/doctrine/migrations/blob/3.6.x/lib/Doctrine/Migrations/Tools/Console/Command/DiffCommand.php#L163)

Answer (score 0):

Just give a try updating your schema

```
php bin/console orm:schema-tool:update --force
```